# "Missing Time" in android gradle build profile

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

We have an android app. We are using gradle `2.5` and the android gradle plugin `1.4.0-beta1`.

We have recently added the new databinding plugin (`rc1`), giving us this substantial list of plugins for the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.trello.victor'
apply plugin: 'com.mutualmobile.gradle.plugins.dexinfo'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

all of these are at their latest released version as of this question.

I noticed our build got substantially longer, so I started investigating and saw this with `--profile`

[image: profile result]

Where are the missing 4+ minutes of time?

With a `--debug` I see the following logs:

```
13:28:54.432 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
13:33:17.846 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Task worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 4 mins 52.096 secs.
13:33:17.846 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:compileRetrolambdaDebug (Thread[Task worker Thread 7,5,main]) started.
```

As you can see there is a 4+ minute jump from the log statement saying `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` is "finished executing" to the next log statement saying it is "complete".. with no logs on stderr or stdout in between. Any ideas what is happening in there?

Here is a ticket I opened... https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to gradle-retrolambda 3.2.3-SNAPSHOT has fixed this issue. I have no idea why, as without data binding everything seemed normal speed.